# Is geodesic distance locally approximated by euclidean distance?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. Let $p\in M$. Is it possible to find a chart $\varphi: p\in U \to \mathbb R^d$ such that the geodesic distance $d_M$ on $U$ is close to the euclidean distance $d_E$ on $\phi_i(U_i)$?

More precisely, if I take $\phi_i = \exp^{-1}_p: \{x\in M: d_M(x,p)\le \delta\} \to \{v\in \mathbb R^d: d_E(v,0 )\le \delta\}$, can I find bounds
$$A(p, M ,\delta) \le \frac{d_M(x,y)}{d_E(\exp^{-1}_p(x), \exp^{-1}_p(y))}\le B(p, M ,\delta)\enspace,$$
such that $A(p, M ,\delta)\small{\nearrow} \normalsize1$ and $B(p, M ,\delta)\small\searrow \normalsize1$ as $\delta\to 0$? Presumably, $A$ and $B$ will depend only on the curvature at $p$ and on $\delta$.

Of course, if $x=p$, then $A=B=1$ by the definition of the exponential map. The difficult part is $x,y\neq p$.

I think I know how to derive $B$. I would consider $\delta$ sufficiently small such that the geodesic ball is convex. A path in $\{v\in \mathbb R^d: d_E(v,0 )\le \delta\}$ from $\exp^{-1}_p(x)$ to $\exp^{-1}_p(y)$ induces a path $\gamma$ in $M$ of length

$$l(\gamma) = \int_0^1 \sqrt{g(\gamma'(t), \gamma'(t))} dt$$
with $g(\gamma', \gamma') = \Vert \gamma' \Vert^2 - \frac 1 3 R_{\mu \sigma \nu \tau}(p) ~ \gamma^\sigma \gamma^\tau \gamma'^\mu \gamma'^\nu+ \mathcal O(|\gamma|^3)$. So if $\gamma$ is a straight line, then $\gamma'(t) = \exp^{-1}_p(x) - \exp^{-1}_p(y)$ and $l(\gamma)$ depends directly on $d_E(\exp^{-1}_p(x), \exp^{-1}_q(x))$.

However, I don't know how to find the lower bound $A$.

Comment: Depends on how different the metric  M is from the Euclidean E.

Comment: @Narasimham True, but locally, the metric $g$ is not much different from euclidean. Specifically, in normal coordiantes, $g = g_E + \mathcal O(\delta^2)$.

Comment: By a sufficiently large scaling smaller parts  approximately Euclidean, a curve can be approximated by its tangent. On log plots non-linear plots appear linear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the exponential map provides a diffeomorphism which is $(1+\epsilon)$-bi-Lipschitz on sufficiently small balls, for any $\epsilon>0$.  This follows from the fact that the Jacobian of the exponential map at $p$ is the identity map.

Comment: Thank you. Would you help me to finish the argument? The exponential map $\exp_p$ pushes forward to $d(\exp_p): T_0(T_p M)  \to T_p M$, and under the canonical identification of $T_0(T_p M) \simeq T_p M$, this is the identity. So in, in euclidean space $M=\mathbb R^d$, for $u,v \in T_p M$, $\exp_p(u) \approx p + u$ and  $\exp_p(v) \approx p + v$, hence $d_M(\exp_p(u), \exp_p(v)) \approx \Vert u - v \Vert$. But how would I adapt this to the manifold setting, where addition of points and tangent vectors is not possible?

Comment: Since in a small neighborhood, the exponential map is close to the identity, it distorts distances no more than $1+\epsilon$.  Here we do use the fact that the manifold is sufficiently smooth so that the Jacobian varies continuously.

Comment: How can the exponential map be close to the identity? It is a map between different spaces and maps $0 \mapsto p$?

Comment: The Jacobian (maybe you call it the differential) is close to the identity, not the exponential map.